# How can I tell which program is accessing mysql?

Tags: mysql, raspbian

My server has been really sluggish recently. I checked with `htop`, and it's often stalling on disk reads. I checked with `atop` and `iotop`, and it looks like `mysql` is demanding a lot of diskIO. I haven't investigated streamlining `mysql` yet, but I was wondering if it's possible to tell what program is accessing it. (I have several programs running, such as Nextcloud, tt-rss, ejabberd, nagios.)

```
$ pgrep -a mysql
3422 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
3585 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/mariadb18/plugin --user=mysql --skip-log-error --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
```

How can I tell which program is accessing `mysql`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the command `lsof -n | grep mysql`. Probably a .sock file somewhere in /var.

Comment: Eep! That returned 3969 lines. It contains things like `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/`, `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/`, `/var/lib/mysql/`, and `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, many of them duplicates, but I'm uncertain how to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Try ' | grep -iv \/lib | sort -u'

Comment: If you want network connections to mysql, use 'netstat -an | grep mysql'

Comment: What do your mysql logs say?

Comment: Still 865 lines. I'm not sure how to parse `lsof` output, it looks like the number of columns is inconsistent? Anyway, `| awk '{print $10}' | sort | uniq` is a bit clearer, but it's not like I see anything that relates to process names in the output. I'm not sure that it's necessarily network connections either.

Comment: There is a pid in the output. You can customize the output to some extent. For network connections, try sockstat.

Comment: Hmm… so looks like I'd have to re-enable logging and get back to you. Regarding the pid, `sudo lsof -n | grep mysql | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` gives 3876 of the top hit, whose pid is… `mysqld`. Second is 10 hits of `mysqld_safe`. Then 3 hits of php and 3×11 hits of `apache2`. So that's a bit vague, but is that a ridiculously large amount of `mysqld` hits? i.e. possibly an error in mysql?

Comment: @Sparhawk Well that's not really indicative of anything. The expensive lookups are not shown. What lookups are performed against your DB? How big is the DB? Can you stash it in /dev/shm/somewhere, and discover if load level improves? What's your swappiness? SD swapping is worse than crashing, and breaks your Pi experience.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far (+1)! I've got to go to bed now, but I'll continue this tomorrow. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. SD wear-out is not a real concern, but it may help temporarily stashing the DB in a ramfs. I do this. I also do not like having a swapfile on Pi, unless it's on an external USB disk with its own powersupply.

Comment: Okay, so I'm quite confused. (Bear in mind I know hardly anything about sql.) Firstly, I tried to answer some of your questions by running `mysql -u root -p`, but it seems that I've logged into `MariaDB`? I then attempted to get the [database size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733523/1944384). Most were <1 MB, except for `owncloud_database`, which was 93.5 MB, and `ttrss`, which was 52.0 MB. (I did this as user `root`, but there are more users; not sure if this is important.) I have no swap at all.